# Factory Resetting Phone w/ out computer

Tags: ios, jailbreak, iphone

Today I went to: 
Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Contents and Settings

I did this because I was told that would be the only way to get jailbreak off of my iPhone 5C. However, now my phone has been showing the white buffer icon for the past 2 and a half hours.

I didn't think it was suppose to take this long to restore my iPhone 5C back to its factory settings? Could it be because it's trying to delete the jailbreak? I really need to delete the jailbreak so I can update my IOS and other features on my iPhone.

P.S: My brothers friend jail broke my iPhone 5C this previous winter.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the jailbreak it is advised to restore the iPhone from the computer, but as you have already reset it mannually I would suggest to download the latest firmware from [here](http://www.felixbruns.de/iPod/firmware/), and then put the phone iPhone into [DFU mode](http://www.iphonehacks.com/put-iphone-in-dfu-mode). Open iTunes and press the restore button holding the <kbd>option</kbd> + **Restore** if on a mac, or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + **Restore** if on PC and select the downloaded ipsw file. This should remove the jailbreak and put you to the latest iOS version for your iPhone.

Comment: It's still showing the buffer icon. I was hoping to make a new icloud account after factory resetting my iPhone. Do I have to use iTunes to fix this or will the buffer icon eventually go away and turn back on?

Comment: Buffer icon? have you tried the method I suggested and it's showing the icon or it is still continuing from the previous process?

Comment: Yeah it's a black screen showing the buffer icon. Like you know the icon that shows up when a video is loading? It sort of looks like that. My iPhone won't connect to my laptop or computer. (I have Dells btw no Macs).

Comment: Never mind! I got it to turn back on by holding the home, power, and volume + buttons. Now it's updating the IOS with Itunes. Thanks for your help!